# Issue with gulp watch task for coffee script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp, gulp-watch

So here is my gulp file

https://gist.github.com/shanejones/79d8ab3985967067e16b

The issue I'm having is that using the default task my coffescript compiles fine but when using the watch task it doesn't.

Is there something blatantly obvious that I've missed.

Thanks in advance.